# Block request URLs that don't contain a specific pattern in chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, developer-tools

**I am going to block any request URLs that don't contain specific pattern.**

There is a request blocking tab in google chrome network tab (after right click on request Row then select block request URL).

[image]

For example I have 7 XMLHttpRequest(XHR) URLs(sent with Ajax) in request blocking tab:

1. http://www.test.com?userid=5
2. http://www.test.com?username=username
3. http://www.test.com?email=email
4. http://www.test.com?name=x
5. http://www.test.com?family=q
6. http://www.test.com?family=y
7. http://www.test.com?family=z

Click on plus sign and block requests that have a specific pattern by adding a pattern(for example the pattern `*family*` blocks 3 below requests):

1. http://www.test.com?family=q
2. http://www.test.com?family=y
3. http://www.test.com?family=z

**Be careful! Because patterns are case sensitive**

[image: pattern for block requests]

**How to block requests that don't contain family word?(the same below)**

1. http://www.test.com?userid=5
2. http://www.test.com?username=username
3. http://www.test.com?email=email
4. http://www.test.com?name=x

Can I use a regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For blocking requests on the client browser, using HTTP Request Blocker and Request blocker extension for google chrome.

For handling requests from clien-side, using below code:
create an interceptor in client-side like below and control all request before and after sending(with AngularJS):

```
myApp.config(['$httpProvider', '$locationProvider',
            function ($httpProvider, $locationProvider) {
            $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q) {
                return {
                    //This method is called right before $http send a
                    //request
                    'request': function (config) {

                    },
                    //This method is called right after $http receives the 
                    //response
                    'response': function (config) {

                    },
                    //request can’t be sent
                    'requestError': function (config) {

                    },
                    //Sometimes our backend call fails
                    'responseError': function (config) {

                    },
                }
            });
        }]);
```

[Request blocker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/request-blocker/cblonkdlnemhdeefhmaoiijjaedcphbf?hl=en)

[Interceptors](http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the DevTools source code

https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/devtools-frontend/blob/aaad45c61dfb22ad885b507a0f38f19863c09553/front_end/network/BlockedURLsPane.js#L194

```
    for (var blockedUrl of this._blockedCountForUrl.keys()) {
      if (this._matches(url, blockedUrl))
        result += this._blockedCountForUrl.get(blockedUrl);
    }
    return result;
  }

  /**
   * @param {string} pattern
   * @param {string} url
   * @return {boolean}
   */
  _matches(pattern, url) {
    var pos = 0;
    var parts = pattern.split('*');
    for (var index = 0; index < parts.length; index++) {
      var part = parts[index];
      if (!part.length)
        continue;
      pos = url.indexOf(part, pos);
      if (pos === -1)
        return false;
      pos += part.length;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

It doesn't use RegEx. So simple answer is No, it doesn't support using RegEx. But you can easily add such a feature and submit them a pull request to allow regex patterns as well

Comment: I am going to block requests from the browser(or any extension) and not from code. I can create an interceptor(in AngularJS) on the code side and check all not contain  'family' patterns before sending any request.

Comment: in your codes, how to block not contain  'family' patterns?
please take into account my URLs in your code.

Comment: It's not my code, i just showed what code is there in DevTools as of now. To tell you what current code does